failed phd admission promise
I got cheated for months in believing a professor's nonsense and lie, he did mentioned that if I could prove continuum hypothesis then I can gain admission for the university math phd.  The university is NUS. I just can't believe that they actually cheated me for it , and I have wasted for months in proving it. Just think about the effort and amount of time I have lost for that. I don't understand

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This is not a place to discuss the accuracy/validity of your proof.

While it probably wasn't appropriate it also seems to have been a test. I think they saw something in your "application" that suggested that you weren't ready and that they gave you an extremely difficult, maybe impossible task, just to see if you would recognize it as such, which you did not.
Had you replied "Very funny!" rather than wasting months on an essentially impossible task you might have fared better.
They didn't lie to you. Had you provided a proof you would probably have been granted a degree and become world famous overnight.

As a mathematician, I'll guess that the CH depends on the axiom system used. There doesn't seem to be contrary evidence with standard axioms, but there might be with a slightly(?) modified system. Non-Standard Analysis has this property. It uses a modified axiom system to demonstrate the "existence" of "epsilons".

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Am I understanding the Wikipedia article on the continuum hypothesis correctly? It asserts that the CH is independent of ZFC, i.e. it (or its negation) could be added to ZFC without affecting its consistency. This seems to suggest that the CH cannot be proved or disproved, which would in turn imply that Had you provided a proof you would probably have been granted a degree and become world famous overnight is impossible (?)

@Allure, ah, if life (and math) were only so simple. A valid proof would imply a flaw in Cohen's work, which won a Fields Medal. Extremely unlikely, but not necessarily impossible. I haven't followed up on this but a model of sets in which the CH definitely did not hold would be interesting if  it were consistent with ZFC. I don't know if such exists.
